# avro to dynamic class creation

Tags: java, bytecode, avro

I'm required to generate a framework that takes many different object types that have been converted to AVRO and placed on a queue, read by a service, turned into byte code without the original class using the avro schema, the namespace replaced with one known by a server and the object handed to a rules engine.

For instance:

public class com.abc.WorkItem {

```
  public String name;
  public String city;

  public WorkItem(String name, String city) {
     this.name = name;
     this.city = city;
```

}

WorkItem item = new WorkItem("Me", "HomeTown");

convert to avro object -> send to queue as avro ( say GenericRecord) ->
read from queue -> generate new class com.xyz.data.WorkItem, create new WorkItem
Object and assign incoming "name" and "city", hand new work item to rules engine.

Avro is not a problem, tried jsonschema2pojo and it does not understand the avro schema. Have looked at ByteBuddy but it does not appear to create classes from schemas.

The idea is for the rules engine and associated code not to require the class that was input because there will be too many to manage. But yet build the WorkItem object which will change between rules engine instances which there will be many.

There are many pieces to the puzzle and I feel the answer is there but I don't see it.

Thanks

Comment: Why not handle everything as `GenericRecord`s?

Comment: I need getters/setters that match getName() getCity() and the GenericRecords that I have generated don't have that feature.

Comment: Have you found a decision?